# Swift core data many-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2, entity-relationship

Swift Core Data many-to-many relationship , how do you save the relationship.

lets suppose there is 2 entities Event and Member, an event can have many members associated with and a Member can have many events...

so

Event <<-->>Member

relationship

events - Event - members
members - Member - events

how would you code saving this kind of relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont have to any code to establish the relationship between entities Event and Member buddy :)

You can open up core data model, select the Event entity, hold the control and drag the mouse over Members entity :) Relationship will be established immediately :)

Now select the relationship change it to many to many from both Event to Member(many-to-many-relationship) and Member to Event(inverse relationship) :)

Now name those relationships at both Event and Member entity appropriately :)

Like Many to Many relationship in event be named as involves_Members and same relationship in Member entity will be named as involvedin_Events :)

Now when you generate the model classes for both entities you will find

```
Events.h
```

has a property named involves_Members which will be of type `NSSet`

and similarly

```
`Members.h`
```

has a property named involvedin_Events which will be of type `NSSet` as well :)

Now assume if you want to add the member to Events all you have to do would be

create a Member object as

```
    [context performBlock:^{

    Member *member = (Member *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Member"  inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [member setValue:@"yourValue" forKey:@"yourkey"];
    //after populating it with appropriate value set the relationship with event :)
    //get the event to which you want to set the relationship with member using NSFetchRequest :)

    //assuming you have event object with you 
    NSMutableSet *involvedMembers = [event mutableSetValueForKey:@"involves_Members"];
    [involvedMembers addObject:member];

    [event setValue:involvedMembers forKey:@"involves_Members"];

    //thats it you are done now 
    //save the context now :)
    NSError *error;  
    [context save:&error];
}];
```

And when you want to access all the members involved in and event all you have to do is to get the event object using NSFecthRequest :) and once you have the event object you can access all its members by using,

```
NSArray *membersArray = [event.involves_Members allObjects];
```

**OR**

```
NSArray *membersArray = [event valueForKey:@"involves_Members"];
```

That's it :) Same thing is applicable for members enity as well :)

**TIP**

You dont want the delete operation to mess with your core data :) So select both the relationships `involves_Members` and `involvedin_Events` and set the delete rule to **Nullify**

Hope I made my point clear :) Happy coding buddy :)

Comment: Thank you for your clear reply. Do you have a swift version?

Comment: @kupilot : Sorry buddy dont have imac with me now will try to provide you the code by tomorrow :) But converting this to swift shouldnt be a problem :)  Here is a link I believe you might have seen it :) If not please have look at it :) https://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates Everything I mentioned is very clearly explained and its in swift :) Hope it helps you :)